# storybook.js, page stuck loading, no errors

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, rollupjs, storybook

I'm building a little react library and trying to get storybooks to work. When I'm starting storybook with `start-storybook -p 6006` the page gets stuck at loading, and there is no errors in the console or in my terminal. I have no idea how to debug this.

[image]

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "icon-lib",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "icon library",
  "main": "dist/bundle.js",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "test": "test",
    "start": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/plugin-external-helpers": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.3.18",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.3.18",
    "@storybook/addons": "^5.3.18",
    "@storybook/react": "^5.3.18",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-inline-react-svg": "^1.1.1",
    "commonjs": "0.0.1",
    "rollup": "^2.6.1",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^4.4.0",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^5.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-replace": "^2.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-require-context": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.42.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/external-helpers",
    "@babel/transform-runtime",
    ["module-resolver", { "root": ["./src"] }],
    [
      "inline-react-svg",
      {
        "svgo": {
          "plugins": [
            {
              "cleanupIDs": true
            },
            {
              "removeTitle": true
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
  ]
}
```

Have I missed something fundamental here?

Comment: Have you got something in your shell?

Comment: @keikai something?

Comment: Never mind, just thought if neither console nor shell caught this problem, it may worth an issue. And I just want to reproduce what you have got

Answer (score 0):

For me, this happened when I changed a component and did not update the story and parent components accordingly. After fixing those errors and restarting storybook, it worked.